# connection of java and R with Rserve

Tags: java, r, rserve

I have java application for analysis for which need to have R installed. I have R also installed in my system and I installed Rserve library. But when I am trying to implement command Rserve() in my R console, following error is coming:

SOCK_ERROR: bind error #98(address already in use)

I have installed all the prerequisite, along with Rserve, needed for my java application and I think these are working fine except Rserve. Can anybody help me out from this predicament?

The tool name is cytoscape along with that I want to run DvD application for which it is throwing error. And operating system is Linux (CentOS).

Thanks,
Mandar

Comment: address already in use means you already have a program using the port used by Rserve. It may be another Rserve already running for instance. Check the running processes, or change to port used by Rserve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it means that you have a running server on the same host and on the same port. It could be caused by a previous execution who never shut down the server. You could try connecting to the server and shut it down, if you have a client, or verify if there's a server running. Since you are on CentOS you could understnd with a :

```
ps faux | grep Rserve
```

If you see a row like

```
root     23762  0.0  0.7 211304 28632 ?        Ss   14:11   0:00 /usr/lib64/R/bin/Rserve
```

then you know you have it. You could kill the server and re-run your tool.