# How to close Rserve from the command line

Tags: r, rserve

this question relates to [close connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264328/connection-of-java-and-r-with-rserve) and perhaps also to this [close Rserve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225066/how-can-i-shut-down-rserve-gracefully). However, in the later case there are connections open and in the first case the answer does not specify how to "kill" the server.

It is important to say that I am new to Rserve, and I have used it for the 1st time today for some mild R-python interaction. I started Rserve from the command line as:

```
% R CMD RServe
```

I though I had closed the connection after the session, but when I now try to re-start Rserve again with a new configuration I get the error:

```
% ##> SOCK_ERROR: bind error #48(address already in use)
```

which is pretty clear. Moreover `ps ax | grep Rserve` returns:

```
% ps ax | grep Rserve
18177   ??  Ss     0:00.33 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rserve
18634 s006  U+     0:00.00 grep Rserve
```

which I understand that indeed means that the server is running. I have tried a few things:

```
% R CMD RSclose
 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rcmd: line 62: exec: RSclose: not found

% R CMD RSshutdown
 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rcmd: line 62: exec: RSshutdown: not found
```

and finally

```
% R CMD shutdown
 shutdown: NOT super-user
```

I am wondering, should I then run:

```
% sudo R CMD shutdown
```

(I would like to make sure before running that command, in case I screw something)

Anyway, the question would be very simple. How can I close server to re-run it.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confused:

```
 R CMD something
```

will always go to R. And `R` no longer knows `Rserve` is running even though you may have started it via `R CMD Rserve`: these are now distinct processes.

What you should do is

```
 kill 18177       # or possibly  kill -9 18177
```

and there are wrappers to `kill` which first grep for the name and find the PID for you:

```
 killall Rserve   # or possibly  killall -9 Rserve
```

The `-9` sends a higher-order `SIGKILL` (ie 'really go and die now') intensity than the default of -15 for `SIGTERM`) (ie 'please stop now').

Comment: Many thanks Dirk for solving my confusion. I rarely use R CMD, so I had many fronts there to be confused by. Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure. I am a big fan of Rserve.

Comment: I just started using it and to be honest I still do not fully understand its "power" (I know that is basically a server, but surely there is more to it). I have been using pyRserve all day. Still do not understand well how R and python communicate through Rserve, but is just a matter of time. I feel this is going to be very useful!