# stop or restart the R CMD Rserve in ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, rserve

Actually I want to stop the Rserve or restart it 
I have read this [How to close Rserve from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052985/how-to-close-rserve-from-the-command-line) but I think if I kill it, it will shut it down and I cannot start it again.

I only want to refresh it so that it will recognize the packages I installed or upgrade. 
When i try to run it as follows:

```
R CMD Rserve

R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Rserv started in daemon mode.

##> SOCK_ERROR: bind error #98(address already in use)
```

I get this error, anyone knows what I should do?

note that on the ubuntu this command line does not function

```
R CMD something
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"address already in use" means that you have `Rserve` already running on the same port. The easiest way to shutdown `Rserve` is via

```
killall -INT Rserve
```

Once it's down, you can start it again using `R CMD Rserve`.

Comment: thanks Simon, this way we don't kill it forever right? we just shut it down temporary